# Dragging image is not contained by panel control

Tags: asp.net, panel, draggable, drag

I'm having a little trouble with my panning functionality in my Dev environment.  The way I implemented panning functionality adding JQuery to drag an image behind a panel control.  The panning functionality is available after zooming into the image.  So I zoom into the image with zoomin/zoomout functionality, then I pan or drag the image behind the panel control.  This works great in my local environment and even when I deploy the website to my local IIS.  However, when I deploy to the Dev server, the image does not stay behind the panel control or is not contained within it.  Are there any suggestions on what might be causing this?  Below is some information on approaches I've tried.

I did a comparison on the two environments.

### Configuration on my local environment:

.NET Compact Framework 2.0 SP2 (Version 2.0.7045)
.NET Compact Framework 3.5 (Version 3.5.7283)
.NET Framework 4 Client Profile (Version 4.0.30319)
.NET Framework 4 Extended
.NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack
AJAXControlToolkit:  Version 3.5.50508.0

### Configuration on Dev Server:

.NET 2.0:  .NET 2.0 SP2 (Version 2.2.30729)
.NET 3.0:  .NET 3.0 SP2 (Version 3.2.30729)
.NET 3.5:  .NET 3.5 SP1 (Version 3.5.30729.1)
AJAXControlToolkit:  Version 1.0.20229.0

Could it be that the slight mismatch in versions is causing the problem?  I was thinking of somehow matching the .NET versions on my local machine to that of the dev server.  Would this cause an issue?  Also I am using Visual Studio 2008 Team System SP1 for development.

I tried adding the AJAXControlToolkit.dll file to the Dev server, but I get the same results.

I tried setting the panel control to style="overflow:hidden", but that didn't seem to work either.

Here is the piece of code I think is causing the problem:

```
                <div id="draggable" style="position:relative;" onmousedown="makeDraggable(); return false;">
                    <img id="myimage" src="[path to image]" usemap="#circles" onmouseover="changeToHand()" />
                </div>

            </asp:Panel>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was isolated to IE.  Mozilla and Chrome were fine.  So I went to the configuration on IE and realized compatibility view settings were on.  If you are on an intranet, make sure the compatibility view settings are off for that too.

Comment: Does anyone know a way to avoid configuring compatibility view?  The user probably should not have to do this to view the site correctly.

Comment: The issue was isolated to IE.  Mozilla and Chrome were fine.  So I went to the configuration on IE and realized compatibility view settings were on.  If you are on an intranet, make sure the compatibility view settings are off for that too.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a root cause answer.  Can anyone help?